# Rails 3 install a branched gem from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, github, bundler

I am trying to install the gem from https://github.com/raid5/paths_of_glory/tree/rails3

When I put the following line of code in my gemfile as specified in step 1 of the readme:

```
gem 'paths_of_glory', :git => 'git://github.com/raid5/paths_of_glory.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

I then run "bundle install" and get the following message:

> Fetching git://github.com/raid5/paths_of_glory.git
>   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:559:in 
>   ': No such file or directory - git clone "git://github.com/raid5/paths_of_glory
>   .git" "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/paths_of_glory-e6d58ab38
>   da51ed00031d8072c6aad8102babf9e" --bare --no-hardlinks (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/sourc
>   e.rb:559:in `git'
>           from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/sourc
>   e.rb:618:in`cache'

...(Several more lines of from)

> ```
>     from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
>     from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
> ```

Any idea what's going wrong?  I appreciate it.  I'm using rails 3 and my os is window 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be your issue, but that's the error I'd expect to see if you didn't have git installed. If you haven't installed it yet, make sure you install it with the command line options.

Comment: You were right on the money.  I do have git installed, but I have been running bundle install in the command prompt without any problems before now, but in this instance "bundle install" from the git bash console solved the issue...Wasted an hour on such a silly problem.  Thanks.

Comment: To avoid it in the future add your git install to your PATH.

Comment: @Preacher -- What do you mean by have git installed. What gets installed for git?